# Why does conversion from int to float not take place when we pass 'int' to a function expecting float in C?

Tags: c, function, type-conversion, undefined-behavior

I wrote a simple program below which calculates the sum and return the result to main(). The main() then calculates the average.
SumOfArray() expects float but I am passing an array of integers. I expected that the integers would be converted into float type implicitly. i.e 35 would be passed as 35.0 but to my surprise it was 0.
the short explanation from whatever I could find is that the behavior is undefined because in this case the typecast happened not from (int)->(float) but (int*)->(float*)

However why does the function SumOfArray() see 0 instead of actual integers if it is reading from the same location. I checked this by printing the address of array both in main() and SumOfArray(). They were same.
Is there anything specific about this mentioned in ISO C standards? The size of integer and float on my machine is 4 bytes so I expected it would read same values albeit with loss of precision.
Following is my program. I printed the values of array passed to the function in SumOfArray.
I am using gcc compiler , codeblock ide compiling for x86_64. Tried this on debian as well.

```
#include<stdio.h>

float SumOfArray(const float array[],unsigned int size)
{
  float sum=-1.0;
  if(size!=0&&array!=0)
  {
    sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
      sum+=array[i];
      printf("sum in sum of array is%f\n",sum);
      printf("array[%d] is %f\n",i,array[i]);
    }
  }
  return sum;
}

int main()
{
  int gradesI[]={35,56,88,23,45,99};
  unsigned int sizeI = sizeof(gradesI)/sizeof(int);
  
  float sumI = SumOfArray(gradesI,sizeI);
  printf("the sum of is %f\n",sumI);
  
  float average = sumI/sizeI;
  printf("the average is %f\n",average);
  
  return 0;
}
```

```
- *output*
sum in SumOfArray is 0.000000
**array[0] is 0.000000**
sum in SumOfArray is 0.000000
**array[1] is 0.000000**
sum in SumOfArray is 0.000000
**array[2] is 0.000000**
sum in SumOfArray is 0.000000
**array[3] is 0.000000**
sum in SumOfArray is 0.000000
**array[4] is 0.000000**
sum in SumOfArray is 0.000000
**array[5] is 0.000000**
the sum of is 0.000000
the average is 0.000000
```

Comment: You're passing a pointer.  It's not going to create a temporary array, populate it with integers, and pass its address as the function argument.  You need to do that yourself.  As it is now, you have a pointer type mismatch which should have generated a compile-time warning.  Don't even bother trying to run the code until you fix that.  It can't possibly work.

Comment: You are correct that using an int where a float is expected will cause automatic conversion. A pointer is a different matter and should have given a warning or error when compiling. Fix all warnings and errors in your code.

Comment: You should have gotten a compiler warning that should be considered as an error: https://godbolt.org/z/58GdT7Gj6. Consider most (if not all) compiler warnings as errors, especially those containing the words _incompatible_ and _implicit_.

Comment: The int value 35 (0010 0011 binary) interpretet as float in IEEE 754 is some very small value (~5e^-44). Unless you print 44 digits after the decimal point, it will read as 0.0000. Note that this interpretation is based on assumptions, and Undefined Behaviour is undefined - you cannot rely on this!

Comment: @king_nak That assumes the `float` has the same endianness as the `int` and many other things that may or may not be the case.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 That's true. Maybe I should have highlighted more the part "this interpretation is based on assumptions", and that there are a lot of those (it's not said that it is IEEE754, too)... As this is UB land, all bets are off anyway. I just found it helpful for understanding, why a certain behaviour is observed on a concrete machine/run, even if it cannot be relied on

Comment: Yes all of you are right. I realized I am passing int* instead of int ( i mentioned that in the details). I was curious about what does C standard actually say about it and why it was reading all 0s.  @king_nak it does make sense.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense, IF the assumtions are valid. But from the C Standard perspective: it's Undefined Behaviour. You cannot predict anything at all, never, and it may change at any time, machine, or "just because". This is the most important takeaway. In theory, the compiler can assume UB never happens, and change the compiled code accordingly (this is what caused a linux kernel vulnarbility by a GCC update: https://lwn.net/Articles/342330/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing a `int` but a pointer to `int` (decayed from a array of `int`) and you don't expect a `float` but a pointer to `float`.

What you have in memory `gradesI`:

```
+------+------+------+------+-
| int  | int  | int  | int  | ...
+------+------+------+------+-
```

When you call a function with `gradesI` as argument, it decays to a pointer to `int`, a pointer that points to `gradesI[0]`.

What `SumOfArray()` expects the pointer pointing to in memory

```
+------+------+------+------+-
| float| float| float| float| ...
+------+------+------+------+-
```

What you ask is why the `int` array isn't converted automatically to a `float` array. There are multiple reasons:

- In c only the argument itself (i.e. the pointer) gets converted. A pointer to `int` shouldn't be implicitly converted to a pointer to `float`, because you can't access a `int` through a `float` pointer (when you try it you get undefined behaviour).
- The compiler would have to generate a new temporary array and passing a pointer to the new temporary array. But that would break a lot of code since we expect the pointer in the function to point to the same location as in the caller.
- The compiler doesn't know how many `int`'s it should convert to `float`.
- Even if the compiler knows that, it would be time consuming.

Answer (score 2):

> SumOfArray() expects float

No, it expects *pointer to* `float`.

> but I am passing an array of integers.

No, you are passing *pointer to* `int`, by virtue of the automatic conversion (decay) of array to pointer.

> I expected that the integers would be converted into float type implicitly.

If the parameter in fact had type `float`, and the argument had type `int`, then there would indeed be an automatic conversion from the latter to the former, but that is not your case.  The C language requires an explicit conversion for the mismatched pointer types actually involved here, but some compilers will perform it implicitly as an extension.  If yours is doing that without even issuing a diagnostic message, however, then you should either turn up its warning level or get a better compiler.

And the reason for an explicit cast and for expecting a diagnostic is that converting the pointer type has no effect on the object to which the pointer points.  After such a conversion, you have a pointer of type `float *` that points at an object of type `int`.  Accessing the `int` via the `float *` produces undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you. I realized I was sending int* instead of int. I also understood that it is reading the binary of 35 as float therefore it is printing all 0s.

Comment: @jane, since you asked about what the language spec has to say, I want to re-emphasize that the spec explicitly denies the "therefore" in your comment.  Again, attempting to read an `int` via a pointer of type `float *` produces *undefined behavior*.  That can take a form as benign as reinterpreting the bits of the pointed-to object as if they were the bits of a `float` (which is different from a value conversion), but that is by no means the only possibility, neither in theory nor in practice.